# Need to clarify the concern about solution for scroll disabling on UIWebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

After searching, I found a solution for scroll disabling on UIWebview (support ios 3.2+):

```
for (id subview in _webview.subviews)
     if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
           ((UIScrollView *)subview).scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Some answers say that this solution causes app rejected. Some answers don't. So please help me to clarify this concern. I really appreciate your helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to submit your app in app store.. then the review team will test your app on the latest iOS available. So if your app don't work on the latest iOS (5.1) then you app will be rejected.

Comment: Hi Saurabh, thanks for your response. Sorry because I made you misunderstand with "support ios < 5.0". I've edited it.

Comment: if your code is working with iOS 5.1 I don't think Apple will reject that.. also you can try - [[[Webview subviews] lastObject] setScrollingEnabled:NO];

Comment: I haven't tried the above code in my apps but I don't think Apple will reject that.. also if you wants to be on safe side then .. you should go with the javascript solution.. if you own the webpage then you can easily insert the code in your webpage.. if you don't own the webpage then you need to inject the javascript in that page

Comment: I own webpage, I've tried a lot but it doesn't work, example: [webviewReview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.ontouchmove = function(event){event.preventDefault();}"];. Can you give me the correct way to do it. Thanks.